# Finding conditions so that the solution of a second order ODE tends to 0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $$y(x)=Ae^{m_1x}+Be^{m_2x}$$ be the general solution to a second order linear homogeneous ODE, with $m_1>0$ and $m_2<0$. If $y(0)=y_0$ and $y'(0)=y'_0$ then find the relationship between $y_0$ and $y'_0$ such that $$y(x)\to0 \text{ as }x\to\infty.$$

I attempted to write the particular solution for the given initial conditions, which I found to be $$y(x)=\frac{1}{m_2-m_1}\left[(y_0m_2-y'_0)e^{m_1x}+(y'_0-y_0m_1)e^{m_2x}\right]. $$Well, if $y_0m_2=y_0'$ then $y(x)\to 0 $ as $x\to\infty$ since $m_2$ is negative. But I don't think that this is what I am expected to find as the question was given after a lecture on equilibrium solutions, critical points, and stable points.

I am mostly looking for hints. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the correct track. You can view this as a stability condition on the initial conditions if you expect it to be viewed in that light. The negative exponential is the only place where you have any x-dependence that can send the solution to zero.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please elaborate on this bit: "view this as a stability condition on the initial conditions"?

Comment: Any perturbations in your initial condition will make your derived condition false because you have a strict equality. To put it in terms of what you discussed in your class would require a working knowledge of the notation and definitions used in your class. If you knew the magnitude of $m_1$ and $m_2$ you could derive stronger stability conditions with inequalities where one exponential will blow up faster than the other.